# Cannot find NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

If I run `where npm` I get:

```
C:\Users\ralbritton\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\ralbritton\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\npm
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\npm.cmd
```

But when I try executing anything with the NPM command I get:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

For reference, I I run

`where node` returns `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` and `node -v` returns `12.16.1`

IT appears that its searching for npm in the wrong directory. How do I change where its looking since I can not access any of the confis through npm commands?

UPDATE: I just happened to open up my command window and was able to run commands just fine. I was using the GIT bash window previously so maybe the problem is with GIT bash?

Comment: This is clearly windows, so my first suggestion would be: close all your terminals, and just reinstall Node (I'd recommend using [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) instead of the nodejs.org installer). Then open a _new_ instance of `cmd` or `powershell` or that-terminal-in-VS-code etc and see if this still breaks.

Comment: I just happened to open up my command window and was able to run commands just fine. I was using the GIT bash window previously so maybe the problem is with GIT bash? I

Comment: entirely possible, never used it in my entire git-using career, so I can't really comment on that aspect. I've always used `cmd`.